# How can I combine these two API's?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Trying to make it so that when a user deletes their account it deletes all their posts too. Eventually I'll have it delete everything related to them too.

```
router.route('/')
    .delete((req, res) => {
      let currentUser = req.user.dataValues;
      return service.removeUser(currentUser.uuid).then(removed => {
        res.json(removed);
      })
    })

router.route('/removeAllProds')  
    .delete((req,res) => {
      let currentUser = req.user.dataValues;
      return service.removeAllUserProds(currentUser.uuid).then(removed => {
        res.json(removed);
      })
    })
```

These are the functions being pulled

```
removeUser(userUuid) {
    return this.models.User.destroy({
      where: {
        uuid: userUuid
      }
    })
  }
removeAllUserProds(userUuid) {
    return this.models.Product.destroy({
      where: {
        sellerUuid: userUuid
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if the user is deleted from database then all of associated/related to this user will be deleted as well. If yes, you need to turn your question into more detail, what database or ORM are you use.

Here is some example if you use mongodb, mysql/postgresql:

- Mongoose(mongodb) you can use the pre 'remove' middleware

```js
// create article schema
const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
  },
  author: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

// create user schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
  },
});
// the below middleware will remove all article related to this user/author
userSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
  this.model('Article').deleteMany({ author: this._id }, next);
});
```

You can read all the documentation regarding [pre hooks here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre)

- If you use SQL (MySql/PostgreSql) with Sequelize as ORM:

```js
  const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  });
  User.associate = models => {
    User.hasMany(models.Article, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
  };
```

At relational database they already provide a rule called `ON DELETE CASCADE`, which mean if you delete the parent record then any child records are also deleted. [Here is a link](https://www.its-all-writing.com/entry/2019/04/13/210607?utm_source=feed) for more detail example on sequelize.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer it put me on the track I needed. We are using psql and sequelize. I've been using postman to test my api and it shows that my delete api is working properly so I wouldn't have realized I had it all wrong. The discussion you linked didn't get posted could you please post the link? 
Thanks again!

Comment: Nice to hear that, I just update the link to a related article with quite good explanation